# Problem about common class

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

first of all, sorry for title, but is very hard explain good in few words. 
Then il problem is this. I have two class(object): Tclass1 and Tclass2. These are indipendent from them and both classes(objects) call a third class(object): for example Tclass3.
As i can share info of Tclass3 between Tclass1 and Tclass2?

Try to explain better with a example:

```
Tclass1 = class
private
  class3: Tclass3;
public
  property err: Tclass3 read class3 write class3;
  ...
end;

Tclass2 = class
private
  class3: Tclass3;
public
  property err: Tclass3 read class3 write class3;
  ...
end;

Tclass3 = class
private
  icode: word;
public
  property code: word read icode;
  ...
end;
```

and main program is:

```
var
  class1: Tclass1;
  class2: Tclass2;
begin
  class1 := Tclass1.create;
  try
    class2 := Tclass2.create;
    try
      class2.err := class1.err;  // <--- problem is here
         ...
         ... // processing...
         ... 
      class1.err := class2.err;  // <--- problem is here
      writeln (class1.err.code)      
    finally
      class2.free; 
    end;
  finally
    class1.free;
  end;
end;
```

of course, in Tclass1 and Tclass2 i call create method of Tclass3 and instance it. Now when i run it, make a exception, but i can't read it becouse console is closed fastly.
I have applied to a class(object) same rules of a variable; infact if i use a variable to place of it, all work fine.
Not is possible solve same with class(object)? 
Thanks again very much.

Comment: This is not your real code. It won't compile as it is, as you declare private fields of `TClass3` before you've declared it. You should post real code, changing it only enough to remove extraneous information and anonymize it if needed. Posting made-up code can change or hide the actual problem, and makes it hard to help you. Also, saying `there's an error` or `throws an exception` without any information about what the error or exception is means nothing. Post the **exact** error or exception message, including any addresses given with the exception. We can't see your screen from here.

Comment: Also, you can see the exception if you add a `try..except` block, and in that exception block `WriteLn` the exception message and then do a `ReadLn` to stop the console window from closing. A bare console application created by the IDE has the block prewritten for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. But let me try to understand.

1. You have two classes, that own an instance of a third class. (They are responsible for creating and deleting the class).
2. You want to share information (but not the class itself) between the two classes.

In that case, you could create an Assign method that copys the fields of one object to another object:

```
Tclass3 = class
private
  icode: word;
public
  procedure Assign(const AValue: TClass3); virtual;

  property code: word read icode;
  ...
end;

procedure TClass3.Assign(const AValue: TClass3);
begin
  Assert(AValue<>nil);
  icode := AValue.icode;
end;
```

If you want to share the same object between the two, you need to decide which of the classes owns the object. (Or you could even create a separate owner). But a better solution would be to use an interface to TClass3, so you could take advantage of reference counting.

Comment: Please don't answer non-questions like this. It does nothing to make the question useful to others in the future, and it encourages other bad questions from this poster and others. (Note I'm not down-voting either the original question or your answer, BTW.) Not answering them until they're edited into real questions helps keep this site a useful resource and reduces noise and clutter. :)

Comment: @Ken That's quite a U-turn you just made.

Comment: @David: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Are you referring to the `HTTPRio` question I answered? It contained actual code that the asker was using, and even though the error message was missing there was enough info IMO to make an answer possible. This one contains absolutely nothing useful (including code) that you can use to do so. Note that's just my opinion, which is why I didn't downvote this question or Gamecat's answer.

Comment: Well, you answered the question yourself. Now you are casting judgement on Gamecat who is just trying to help. I think it's mean to give Gamecat grief for this.

Comment: @David: I posted an answer, realized that because of the lack of information it was probably not right, and **immediately** deleted it (less than 30 seconds after posting it). There's a difference, isn't there? Also didn't give grief; I did NOT downvote, and didn't cast any aspersions or insult GC. How is that "grief"?

Comment: @gamecat, Thanks very much, so work. sorry for my english, i know that not is much good.

Comment: @Ken White, is this a new policy I'm not aware of? Yes, the question is vague, but it's probably because the original poster has problems with the english language. And I don't thinkl that is a reason to exclude somebody.

Comment: @GameCat: I can't speak for policy; I just answer questions. I just posted my opinion. What I do believe is that you answered a question that, because of it's lack of information, has no use to future readers/searchers. The acceptance of your answer means that the OP isn't going to clarify the question, and as it is it is useless for anyone else later. If we don't answer non-questions, we encourage people to post better ones, and they are available for people searching for answers in the future. It may have earned you rep, but it's meaningless otherwise, and that's detrimental to this site.

Comment: @ken while I definitely agree with the sentiment, this is hardly the most egregious example of a bad question getting a good answer.. I'd save the lectures for a stronger example. Funny thing about incentive systems, sometimes they work a little too well...

Comment: @Jeff, fair enough. :)  (I didn't think I was lecturing, but I can delete my comments.) I didn't downvote either the question or the answer, as I asked the OP to clarify it. I didn't vote on GC's answer because it appears to be correct, and since the OP accepted it it seemingly was. :)

Comment: @ken it is indeed a very real issue, and continues to be a concern... but there are far better (aka worse..) examples out there.

Comment: @Jeff, OK. Will try to judge a little better. :)

Answer (score 1):

> *"Now when i run it, make a exception, but i can't read it becouse
>   console is closed fastly."*

You can solve that problem as follows:

In the .dpr file of your console application you probably have something like this:

```
begin
  try
    // do stuff
  except
    on e:Exception do
      writeln(e.message);
  end;
end.
```

Just change it into this:

```
begin
  try
    // do stuff
  except
    on e:Exception do
    begin
      // show error, and wait for user to press a key
      writeln(e.message);
      readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

That should make debugging a bit easier.

Comment: That - while being certainly helpful - is not an answer to the question.

Comment: ...and that's why it should be a comment...the OP can then edit the question and add information he gathered using the comment...and can then accept an answer to the *real* problem.